# How do I "restart" if statement if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

I'm very new to javascript. I wanted to make a quick program that generates the youngest age possible a person is able to date given their age, using the formula my dad taught me. In my code I have a condition where if my var (dateage) isn't a number, the user is asked to please enter in a number. I want the program to then re-ask the variable assignment prompt until a number is given.

```
var dateage = prompt("How old are you?");

if(dateage >= 14){
    dateage = dateage/2 + 7;
    alert("The youngest you can date is " + dateage)
} else if(isNaN(dateage)){
   alert("Please enter in a number");
} else
   alert("You're too young to date.");
```

You can see that if dateage isn't a number, the user is alerted. At that point I want the prompt to appear again asking the user for their age. How can I do this?

Comment: You'll need to use loops of one form or another. A simple `do..while` would be sufficient.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gCqqR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a *function* so you can re-invoke

```
function checkAge() {
    var dateage = prompt("How old are you?");

    if(dateage >= 14){
        dateage = dateage/2 + 7;
        alert("The youngest you can date is " + dateage)
    } else if(isNaN(dateage)){
       if (confirm("Please enter in a number")) checkAge();
    } else
       alert("You're too young to date.");
}
checkAge();
```

I used a [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm) for the re-check because this means you can more easily escape from an infinite loop situation. If you don't want to pollute the namespace, you can write this as a named *IIFE*, and if you don't want to carry the stack over, you can invoke through a *setTimeout*.

Comment: Nice timing guys, 3 same answers within 10 seconds :D

Comment: This seems so simple. I guess the actual implementation is the hardest part of learning this stuff. Thanks a lot. I tested it and it does exactly what I hoped it would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in a function and simply keep recalling the function:

```
function askAge(){
   var dateage = prompt("How old are you?");

   if(dateage >= 14){
      dateage = dateage/2 + 7;
      alert("The youngest you can date is " + dateage)
   } else if(isNaN(dateage)){
      alert("Please enter in a number");
      askAge();
   } else
      alert("You're too young to date.");
}

askAge();
```

Comment: It worked when I did that. Thanks a ton to you and Paul S. For the almost instantaneous responses.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the question and output in a while loop, breaking only when number has been entered

Comment: I like this approach, but it would be great if you could add an example to your answer. Here's a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/D5Kn6/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to have "restartable" functions look like:

```
(function() {
    var restart = arguments.callee; // "magic" property refers to current function
    if( somecondition) setTimeout(restart,1);
    else {
        // do actual stuff
    }
})();
```

The `setTimeout` released the current call stack, otherwise you could potentially get a stack overflow error if you manage to infinitely loop `restart`.

Comment: You could also name the anonymous function.  `(function restart(){ // code }());`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat if it's got a name, it's no longer _anonymous_ and is instead a _named function expression_. I'll also note that MDN says `Note: You should avoid using arguments.callee() and just give every function (expression) a name.` and `Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode.`

Comment: This is _not_ a good answer for someone who said he is _new_ to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkAge() {
    var dateage = prompt("How old are you?");

    if(dateage >= 14){
        dateage = dateage/2 + 7;
        alert("The youngest you can date is " + dateage)
    } else if(isNaN(dateage)){
       if (confirm("Please enter in a number")) checkAge();
    } else
       alert("You're too young to date.");
}
checkAge();
```